# How to block creation redundant FK Constraint in EF TPH Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, tph

I use in some project EF code First with TPH (in part of classes)
I have class like this:

```
namespace Billing.Model.Domain.Entities.BilProject
{

    [Table("ProjectPriceList")]
    public abstract class ProjectPriceList
    {
        [Key, Column("ProjectId", Order = 0)]
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column("PriceListId", Order = 1)] 
        public int PriceListId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column("PriceListSourceType", Order = 2)]
        public int PriceListSourceType { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PriceListSourceType")]
        public virtual BillingProjectCode PriceListSourceTypeCode { get; set; }
        public int AddUsrnm { get; set; }
        public DateTime AddTmstmp { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
        public virtual BillingProject BillingProject { get; set; }
        public virtual SnapShotPriceList SnapShotPriceList{ get; set; }
    }

    public class BillingProjectPriceList : ProjectPriceList
    {
        [ForeignKey("PriceListId")]
        public virtual PriceList PriceList { get; set; }
    }
    public class EstimateProjectPriceList : ProjectPriceList
    {
    }
}
```

When I try to generate sql code to create a data base by
Update-Database -Script from console
I receive this SQL as result:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProjectPriceList] (
    [ProjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PriceListId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PriceListSourceType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AddUsrnm] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AddTmstmp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Discriminator] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ProjectPriceList] PRIMARY KEY ([ProjectId], [PriceListId], [PriceListSourceType])
)

CREATE INDEX [IX_ProjectId] ON [dbo].[ProjectPriceList]([ProjectId])
CREATE INDEX [IX_PriceListId] ON [dbo].[ProjectPriceList]([PriceListId])
CREATE INDEX [IX_PriceListSourceType] ON [dbo].[ProjectPriceList]([PriceListSourceType])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProjectPriceList] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ProjectPriceList_dbo.BillingProject_ProjectId] FOREIGN KEY ([ProjectId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[BillingProject] ([ProjectId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProjectPriceList] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ProjectPriceList_dbo.BillingProjectCode_PriceListSourceType] FOREIGN KEY ([PriceListSourceType]) REFERENCES [dbo].[BillingProjectCode] ([CodeId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProjectPriceList] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ProjectPriceList_dbo.PriceList_PriceListId] FOREIGN KEY ([PriceListId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PriceList] ([PriceListId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

The last FK Constraint is redudant and make me trouble if i try add new EstimateProjectPriceList.
My question is
How to stop create this FK by some code Data Annotations or Fluent Api in OnModelCreating ?

Thnx for any help..

Comment: What is the meaning of the PriceListId for a EstimateProjectPriceList?

Comment: No meaning.
Only when I insert BillingProjectPriceLis, I would like to have access to the whole object PriceList. EstimatingProjectPriceList comes from external source

Comment: But you have PriceListId as a key property for EstimateProjectPriceList.  You need to rethink your model.

Comment: I've composite key (built from 3 columns). Generally PriceListId is only part of my Primary Key, but in BillinghProjectPriceList case , this field is also foreign key to another table and I would like to use this reference in this case. It  all works. Only one problem is creation in sql redudant constraint. So ... what is the best way of implementation situation like this ?  

I don't want to create a separate table for Estimating and Billing